# Rails Admin Form Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, semantics, rails-admin

I have a form for movies in rails, and one of the columns is called year.
In my rails form it is displayed as such

```
<%= f.collection_select :year_id, Year.all, :id, :year %>  </div><br />
```

and it outputs this

[image]

But in Rails Admin, on the form for Movies, the years are shown as such

[image]

So how can I make it show the actual year number (2012) and  not Year #3

Answer (score 0):

In app/models/year.rb

```
def name
  year
end
```

Or use label_method to specify which method you want to be used as a label method for all the instances of the class.